# Handling system event for switch user

Tags: c#, events, system, handle

I need to close serial port and kill application when user switch to another user. Is it possible to handle when user switch to another user?

Here is my code that i can handle when user log off but cannot handle when switch user.

```
static void SystemEvents_SessionEnding(object sender, SessionEndingEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Reason)
    {
        case SessionEndReasons.Logoff:
            serialPort1.Close();
            Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
            break;

        //Here i want handle process for switch user
        //case SessiondEndReasons.SwitchUser??
        //      serialPort1.Close();
        //      Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
        //      break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to fire your code in response to the [`SystemEvents.SessionSwitch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionswitch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event instead:

```
SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += (sender, args) =>
            {
                serialPort1.Close();
                Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
            };
```

Here are the possible reason you can handle too:

More info:

- [`SessionSwitchEventArgs` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.sessionswitcheventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [`SessionSwitchReason` Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.sessionswitchreason%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)